# XML to String

Tags: java

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory f_server = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            f_server.setValidating(false);
            DocumentBuilder builder_server = f_server.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc_server = builder_server.parse(url);

            String = // строка xml хранящегося в doc_server.
```

Comment: doc_server.toString()?

Comment: А зачем вообще городить фабрики и билдеры, чтобы потом считать в строку?

Comment: тоже вариант, можно просто считать HTTP клиентом

Comment: doc_server.toString()? // пробовал не работает. возвращает #document: null.
Я просто привёл часть кода для наглядности. Вроде бы просто из Document преобразовать в String.

Comment: значит null

Comment: ну 
Element rootel=doc_server.getDocumentElement();
      NodeList list = rootel.getChildNodes();      
      for(int i=0; i<list.getLength();i++  )
         {
          System.out.println("+ " + list.item(i).getNodeName() + ":" + list.item(i).getTextContent());
         }
работает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

public Document getDomElement(String xml){
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            // return DOM
            return doc;
            }
Просто и наглядно. А потом делайте со своим дом то что нужно :-)
```

Comment: мне нуна в строку, а не из неё...

Comment: добавил код, смотри

Comment: а какие библиотеки импортировать?

Comment: ctr+shift+o там всё импортнётся само или выберите по логике библиотеки.